# How to implement synchronization of browser-based online games when users refresh their browser

Tags: algorithm, browser, websocket, synchronization

In implementing a browser-based simple game involving multiple users, I have the server save the game state at certain sync points (not time-based but event-specific). I identify each state by an integer.

When a user refreshes his browser, the server provides the latest state and restores the content in the browser. However, in those few seconds while the browser is loading the latest content after browser-refresh, the state could change again. I do not know how to handle this situation because sending the next state will again raise the same issue.

I want a seamless refresh so none of the other players are impacted when one user refreshes his browser (or for that matter leaves and comes back).

The implementation language is not relevant. I use websockets to communicate between the browser and the server. The server is the intermediary for all communication between users (I am not using WebRTC data channels). What is the best way to sync the application content in multiple browsers?

This is indeed a programming-based question though no code is provided.

Comment: The server will send an initial "snapshot" (state of the world) followed by the flow of real-time updates. The client simply needs to process all the events, starting from the snapshot, in sequence.

I wrote an article a few years ago covering several aspects of browser synchronization. You can find it here: https://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/10/optimizing-multiplayer-3d-game.html

Comment: @AlessandroAlinone Yes. Interesting article to get a new perspective on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the fact that your client exists in a browser.  Let's just talk about replication.

The usual approach in databases is to separate snapshots from Write Access Logging (WAL) logs.  When you bring a new client up, you select a snapshot and transfer that.  Then when the client is ready it asks for WAL logs from that snapshot forward.  The same mechanism is used after crashes.  The last available snapshot is loaded, then the WAL log is replayed, then the database comes up.

I would suggest the same strategy.  This does require efficient storage of snapshots.  Some kind of log.  And some kind of replay mechanism.  Which is a lot of easy to mess up code.  If you can use something existing, that would be good.

The first thing that I looked into was using Emscripten to compile Redis to JS, and then try to use Redis' built-in asynchronous replication to replicate to your browser.  That may be possible, but the fact that Redis is single-threaded and wants to be a client-server is probably a showstopper.

The next best option that I found is that you can use https://isomorphic-git.org/.  Here is how that could build what you need.  You simply maintain your current state in a git repository, and keep a WAL log of everything that you've done with it.  When a client connects, it clones the repository.  Once done it connects to the websocket, tells you what commit it is at, and you send it the WAL log from that point forward.  Locally in the browser you run those git commands.  If the client simply loses its connection and then rejoins, it can do a git pull, and then follow the same strategy.

This will be a bunch of work for you.  But a lot less work than implementing everything from scratch.

Comment: Yes. In theory I understand and accept. The problem is that when 'WAL log is replayed", it is assumed that there are no ongoing activities or that there is some kind of locking mechanism in place.  The options you have suggested, I feel are a bit too heavy for a real-time responsive system.

Comment: @Sunny The mechanism in practice is not actually heavyweight.  If it was then no database using it could give acceptable performance.  That said the specific technology choice may be because you're constantly and probably unnecessarily serializing/deserializing to strings.